# Writing a Basic Shell

Tags: c, bash, shell

For my class I have to create a basic shell similar to bash that will allow the user to call commands like ls, sleep, etc.
I am looking for resources on how to do this: tutorials, help text, sample code or even just some general information on how to get started.
Does anyone have an links or info to help me out?

Comment: Do you need it to parse shell scripts (or the arbitrary command line calls like `for x in \`seq 0 10\`; do something; done`?

Comment: No shell scripts, just executing built in linux commands and doing some file structure manipulation

Comment: At a high level, the idea is to read the input string and do a fork/exec.  For piping processes together, combine the fork/exec idiom with dup2 and close to connect the pipes.

Answer (score 12):

It really depends on how simple your shell has to be.  If you don't need job control (i.e. backgrounding) or pipes then it is very simple.  Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 1024

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char line[MAX_LENGTH];

  while (1) {
    printf("$ ");
    if (!fgets(line, MAX_LENGTH, stdin)) break;
    system(line);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

You can exit from the above example with CTRL-D.  To add built-in commands like **exit** or **cd** you would have to tokenize the line using **strtok()** and look at the first token.  Here is a more complicated example with those commands added:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#define chdir _chdir

#else
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

#define MAX_LENGTH 1024
#define DELIMS " \t\r\n"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char *cmd;
  char line[MAX_LENGTH];

  while (1) {
    printf("$ ");
    if (!fgets(line, MAX_LENGTH, stdin)) break;

    // Parse and execute command
    if ((cmd = strtok(line, DELIMS))) {
      // Clear errors
      errno = 0;

      if (strcmp(cmd, "cd") == 0) {
        char *arg = strtok(0, DELIMS);

        if (!arg) fprintf(stderr, "cd missing argument.\n");
        else chdir(arg);

      } else if (strcmp(cmd, "exit") == 0) {
        break;

      } else system(line);

      if (errno) perror("Command failed");
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

You could extend this by adding more build-in commands or by supporting things like **cd** with out arguments to change to your home directory.  You could also improve the command prompt by adding information such as the current directory.

As a side note, an easy way to add a command history and line editing features is to use the **GNU readline** library.

Comment: @AliShakiba ``strtok`` keeps a context.  Passing zero causes it to continue parsing where it left off.  You should read the ``strtok`` man page.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a very basic shell for the [HelenOS project](http://helenos.org). It has the following features:

- Line editing / history
- Buit in commands / loadable commands
- Search path to find external commands
- EXTREMELY basic scripting
- Dumbed down implementations of most of the GNU core utilities (done from scratch) as built in functions.

Most of it is implemented on a very simple re-usable framework built around function pointers. At the minimum, you'll need a built in 'exit' or 'quit' so someone can actually get out of the shell, plus 'cd' and 'pwd'. An 'export' / 'declare' built in would also make sense.

You can look at the code (BSD) licensed [here](http://trac.helenos.org/trac.fcgi/browser/mainline/uspace/app/bdsh). Or download the repo, it's in uspace/app/bdsh. I can probably dig up the last working Linux version, prior to when I ported it if you need it. The biggest difference is the HelenOS version uses a home grown line editor, task_spawn() instead of execve() / posix_spawn(), etc. The rest is portable. It was originally designed just to make testing of features easy and interactive. I didn't implement job control, as it wasn't needed. That could be achieved trivially, however.

If you want to study a 'real' shell, I highly recommend looking at `dash`, you'll find it much simpler to grasp than diving straight into the code of bash.

Anecdotally, 'bdsh' stands for '*brain dead shell*'.

Answer (score 2):

You could look at [BusyBox](http://www.busybox.net) for some very small shell implementations.

Answer (score 2):

If you are starting , try http://stephen-brennan.com/2015/01/16/write-a-shell-in-c/ and further for detailed knowledge http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Data-Structures.html#Data-Structures .

Also , while learning how to program a shell using C/C++ make a habit to refer man pages of commands.

Answer (score 0):

Bash provides very few commands on its own: `cd`, `pushd`, `popd`, the variable handling routines (`set` and `$x`), and all of the control flow items like loops and conditionals. Almost all other commands are found in the `$PATH`.

Unless the assignment states otherwise, ignore variables and control flow. Just provide a [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-eval-print_loop) that looks in `$PATH` and executes whatever the user enters (presumably through `posix_spawn()`) and pass along the command-line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Lowball answer:

If the program is very simple, then simple system calls can be implemented script-like with the command "`system("putdesiredcommandhere");`"

When you install "`printf`" in a program, you are doing a simple system call, with the help of stdio.h.

Small code sample follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
main ()
{
    system ("clear");
    system ("echo this is an example of a basic system call");
    printf ("just as you've always done.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Using that method, you could transcribe bash or csh scripts into a c program.  It would require using a system call for each line in the script.