# Use strtok() and execute UNIX command in background

Tags: c, unix, background, strtok

I'm trying to write a C program which creates a UNIX shell. In this shell when a UNIX command is typed, the shell should execute it in the foreground or background (background when & is specified). I'm getting the command to run in the foreground but I can't run it in the background.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 1024
#define DELIMS " \t\r\n"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *cmd, *bg;
    char line[MAX_LENGTH];
    pid_t fpid,bpid;
    int status;
    while (1)
    {
           fpid=10;
           bpid=10;
            printf("myshell > ");
            if (!fgets(line, MAX_LENGTH, stdin))
                    break;
             int j=0;

            if(cmd = strtok(line, DELIMS))
            {

                    bg = strtok(line," ");
                    while(bg!=NULL)
                    {
                            printf("%s",bg);
                            bg = strtok(NULL, " ");
                            if(strcmp(bg, "&") == 0)
                                    break;
                    }

                    printf("%s", bg);
                    if(strcmp(cmd,"exit")==0)
                            break;

                    else if(strcmp(bg,"&")==0)
                    {
                            bpid=fork();
                            //waitpid(bpid,&status,0);
                            system(line);
                            exit(0);
                    }
                    else
                   {
                            //fpid=fork();
                            //if(fpid==0)
                            //{
                                    system(line);
                            //      exit(0);
                            //}
                            //else 
                            //{
                            //      waitpid(fpid,&status,0);
                            //}
                    }
            }
    }

  return(0);
}
```

This code is for my homework.

Comment: First rule of using strtok: do not use strtok.

Comment: @Eugene than what do I use in place of strtok ?

Comment: strtok_r is the reentrant version

Comment: Can you explain it with my code?

Comment: There are some serious compilation errors in this code that you should fix before submitting it to SO.  If the file is called `fork.c`, then GCC 4.8.1 gives errors such as: `fork.c:33:20: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char *[100]’ from type ‘char *’` at
`if(cmd = strtok(line, DELIMS))`
and `fork.c:46:21: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcmp’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]` at `if(strcmp(cmd,"exit")==0)` with note
`/usr/include/string.h:87:6: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char **’`
`int strcmp(const char *, const char *);`

Comment: Note that `strtok()` and `strtok_r()` both destroy the input line, one of the reasons why they are not appropriate for use in shell command line parsing.  With your code, the different symbols, such as the background `&`, have to be separated from the word before (and after) by spaces, which regular shells do not require.  That needn't be insuperable for a home-brew shell, but won't fly with a POSIX-compatible shell. Because `strtok()` chops up the line, you can't use the line in `system()` afterwards, because only the first word is still there (it'll be OK for `ls` but not `ls -l`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I made changes to the code above. Can you see what's wrong now please?

Answer (score 1):

Read the manpage for `fork()`. The return code of 0 means that you are in the child, non-zero (non-negative) means you are the parent. You should have different logic based on that and use `system()` (or better `exec*()` in the child branch.

Here's the typical logic you should have:

```
tokenize(line)

if (last token is '&') {
    rc = fork();

    if (rc < 0)
        handle error;

    else if (rc > 0) {  /* in parent, rc = child pid */
        do whatever you planned to do in the parent process
    }
    else {  /* in child */
        use exec*() to start the child command
    }
}
else {  /* foreground execution */
    use system() to run command
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for getting back to me. I'm kind of not used to program much with C. Do you mind elaborating more/editing my code?  The program should parse the user input in the shell to get the & and then execute it in the background.

Comment: See the updated comment

Comment: So in which part does the code for background process fit in? And how do I parse for the last token i.e., & ?

Comment: 1. Your background process is started in the line "use exec*() to start the child command." 2. To parse for '&' you need to tokenize the command (and not just by blanks as foo& is a valid command as well) and strcmp(tokens[ntoks - 1], "&")

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't get it :( Do you mind providing an example or editing my code?

Comment: Write a tokenizing function that takes a line and fills an array of strings. Look at `strtok()` library function and run it in a loop. Remember that it is stateful (or use strtok_r() which is not). GFor simplicity assume that every token is blank separated (i.e. you will not use "mycommand&" but will have to put a blank before ampersand). Once you fill the tokens array, check what the last token is. You do want to tokenize as exec() family of calls expects command and args as an array, not as a string.

If you still don't understand, you definitely need to read K&R book.

Comment: I think I got you. I made changes to my code. But when I type 'ls&' the shell is executing the code in the foreground itself. When I type 'ls&' I want the shell to display "shell >" by executing the command in the background. Can you help me out here please?

Comment: Make sure your logic is coded correctly (use debugging or printf) to ensure that you try to spawn ls from the CHILD. In fact, don't use ls - instead create a shell script with "sleep 120" and run it instead to see clearly when it's in progress.

Comment: I tried to do a printf. in the variable 'bg' it is taking 'ls' as the token. I want it to take '&'. How do I do that?

Comment: Sorry if I'm pushing, but can anyone help me here?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I have posted the code above in the first post. I made changes to it.

Comment: I'm using the code provided in the second answer of this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788374/writing-a-basic-shell.   I'd like to know how to execute a UNIX command in the background in that program.

Comment: Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Looks like I've encountered a new problem. I'm getting a segmentation fault (core dumped) when I type "ls" in the shell prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code derived from the code in the question that emits a prompt, gets the line of input, splits it into tokens, detects that the last token is `&`, and detects that the first word is `exit` and exits the loop.  It prints out what its found, carefully.  And you now need to handle the fork, exec, wait etc code.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 1024
#define DELIMS " \t\r\n"

int main(void)
{
    char line[MAX_LENGTH];
    char *ps1 = "toysh> ";

    while (fputs(ps1, stdout) > 0 && fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != NULL)
    {
        char *cmd[100];
        char *bg = NULL;
        int j = 0;
        char *tokens = line;

        while ((cmd[j++] = strtok(tokens, DELIMS)) != NULL)
            tokens = NULL;

        assert(j < 100);
        /* The line has been tokenized into j-1 tokens */
        /* Print the tokens found */
        for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
        {
            if (cmd[i] != 0)
                printf("%d: <<%s>>\n", i, cmd[i]);
            else
                printf("%d: NULL pointer\n", i);
        }

        assert(j > 0);
        if (j == 1)
            continue;   // No command

        j--;

        assert(j > 0);
        if (strcmp(cmd[j-1], "&") == 0)
        {
            printf("== Found &\n");
            bg = cmd[j-1];
            cmd[--j] = 0;
            if (j == 0)
            {
                puts("Syntax error: cannot have & on its own");
                continue;
            }
        }

        if (strcmp(cmd[0], "exit") == 0)
        {
            printf("== Found exit command\n");
            if (bg != NULL)
            {
                puts("Can't run exit in background");
                continue;
            }
            break;
        }

        /*
        ** Now you can do your fork, exec, waitpid work.  Note that the
        ** command is already split into words with the null pointer at
        ** the end.  This is what execv(), execve() and execvp() want
        */

    }
    putchar('\n');

    return(0);
}
```

Note that the code does not prevent you from entering too many tokens on a single line.  It eventually detects that you've done so, if it hasn't already crashed, via an `assert`.  You'll need to make that bullet-proof at some point.

#### Request for further assistance

> I'm very new to the fork and waitpid work. Can you help me here?

You've been given good advice in the other answer.

Add:

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
```

Add:

```
static void run_command(char **argv, int bg_flag);
```

Add:

```
        /*
        ** Now you can do your fork, exec, waitpid work.  Note that the
        ** command is already split into words with the null pointer at
        ** the end.  This is what execv(), execve() and execvp() want
        */
        run_command(cmd, (bg != NULL));
```

New function:

```
static void run_command(char **argv, int bg_flag)
{
    pid_t pid;

    fflush(0);   // Flush pending output

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
        printf("Fork failed\n");
    else if (pid > 0)
    {
        /* Parent shell */
        if (bg_flag == 0)
        {
            int status;
            int corpse;
            while ((corpse = waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG)) >= 0)
            {
                if (corpse != 0)
                    printf("Process %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n",
                           corpse, status);
                if (corpse == 0 || corpse == pid)
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
            printf("%d: %s running in background\n", pid, argv[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        /* Child process */
        execvp(argv[0], argv);
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: failed to execute %s (%d: %s)", (int)getpid(), argv[0], errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

You get to decide how verbose your shell should be, but while you're debugging it, more information is better than less.

Also, the error messages should all go to `stderr`; I've left a fair number going to `stdout`.

Comment: I'm very new to the fork and waitpid work. Can you help me here? Basically if "ls" is typed, the command should run in the foreground by displaying the list of files present in the directory. If "ls &" is typed, then the command should be executed in the background and should immediately display the prompt "myshell >"

Comment: I preferred the `toysh` name (names beginning with 'my' annoy me, whether they're documents folders or DBMS or shells).  See the updates.

Comment: Thank you so much @JonathanLeffler. Your updated code is working fine in the background. But when I type "ls &" it is printing "ls is executing in the background" and also printing the ls output. I don't want it to print the the output of ls. How do I do that?

Comment: You have to provide standard output to the command, so after forking, you can close standard output, and then `open()` the null device, `/dev/null`, and use `dup2()` to ensure that it is connected to `STDOUT_FILENO` (aka file descriptor 1) (and `close()` the file descriptor if it wasn't originally opened on 1) so that the child process will write to `/dev/null`.  Of course, if you're doing I/O redirection (`> some.file`), then you open that file instead of `/dev/null`.

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand many things there. :( because I'm a newbie

Comment: It's OK not to understand them yet; everyone was a newbie once. However, it is now time for you to do a little research, and learning. You can use the [POSIX](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm) materials as a very good guide (though not always explanatory — but look at the information at the bottom of the pages).  I've given you pointers to the names of the functions you need to learn about. Now it is time for you to do the learning. You can also look at the many questions on SO about home-brew shell implementations or the use of pipes. A search for `[c] dup2` should help.

Comment: How do i get your code to run the "jobs" command? Whenever I type "jobs" it says "Failed to execute". Can you help me here please?

Comment: The `jobs` command is a shell built-in; it is not an external executable.  You'll find quite a lot of those over time, including (notoriously) `cd`.  You'll have to recognize and implement `jobs` yourself.  Amongst other things, that means you'll have to keep a record (list) of which processes you start in the background (think about the data structures needed), and keep that list up to date as you recognize that processes have died.

Comment: So I cannot execute "jobs" on the code you'd given?

Comment: If you can find a binary called `jobs`, you can execute it.  You probably won't find a binary called `jobs`, so you won't be able to execute it.  You will have to build it into your shell, like `exit` is built into your shell.